# Intro to COM DLL

Tags: windows, com, dll

Before you tell me "google it" - hear me out. I come from C++ & Perl/Python (on Linux) background but I have a few projects coming up where I have to jump in to Windows development. Specifically creating some COM DLLs (not .Net). BTW, after reading some resources, I do have basic idea of what COM & what DLL is.

I tried to search on Google, but most of the tutorials I encountered assumed some Windows dev experience or at least that is how it seemed to me. So, I was wondering if some one went through a similar path & could probably point in a direction that'd help me get jump started on developing COM DLLs. I have access to VS2005. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you can create COM components in .NET languages, either VB.NET or C#. Also, note that the VS2008 Express Editions are free, so you do not necessarily need to be stuck in the past, at VS2005. Finally, the complete VS2010 Ultimate Edition Release Candidate is available for free download _now_, so you have the chance to be right up to date - it launches in a month.

Comment: I did not know that VS2010 was a free download. I should check it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When programming in VS try [Create a COM Visible Component](http://www.playinthesoup.com/soup/articles/tech/regforcom.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The "no .NET" requirement forces you to write code in unmanaged C++.  COM has a pretty steep learning curve, flattened somewhat by using ATL.  At least will will help you get the basics right.  VS2005 has built-in class wizards to generate the boilerplate code you'll need and keep you code and the IDL in sync.  You'll need a good COM book (hard to find) and Chris Sells' ATL Internals.

Comment: @nobugz: the way I read it wasn't that he can't use .NET, but that he needs to create a COM DLL and not a ".NET DLL". That is, he needs to use COM rather than creating "normal" code.

Comment: Yeah, I should've qualified my statement. This dll is going to be consumed by scripting languages like Perl & Python. So I cannot create managed dlls. At least that is what I learned from my searches. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @John, that's not accurate.  The COM interop support will automatically bootstrap the CLR for you when you use  [ComVisible(true)].  It's going to be a wholeheckofalot easier to get going then ATL.

Comment: thank you for that information. Looks like this might be a much better alternative for me.